# Computing the Fourier transform of a symbolic function

Tags: matlab, fft, symbolic-math

I am trying to graph the Fourier transform of this signal, but it keeps giving me this error:

> Error using fft Invalid data type. First argument must be double, single, int8, uint8, int16, uint16, int32, uint32, or logical

What can I do?

This is my code:

```
syms x
h=(2*heaviside(x-1))-2*heaviside(x-2)
fplot(h, [-4, 4])
xlabel('t');title('x(t)') 
F=fft(h);
fplot((F))
```

Comment: `fft` is a discrete operation. Your `h` is a symbolic function. Try this one instead: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.fourier.html

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked on the matlab forum [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/855790-how-to-do-fourier-transform-fft-on-a-symbolic-function).

All you have to do is call [fourier](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.fourier.html) instead of [fft](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html).

Your code should look something like this:

```matlab
syms x;
h=(2*heaviside(x-1))-2*heaviside(x-2);
fplot(h, [-4, 4]);
xlabel('t');
title('x(t)');
F=fourier(h);
fplot(real(F), [-10, 10]);  % Plotting real part of the transform
```